How to model Bjork inspired rounded shapes (without sculpting, ideally) mask?

I've been seeing a lot of Björk's looks lately (probably thanks to the IG algorithm). Can someone help me figure out how to model this? I'm particularly interested in replicating the rounded shapes, as shown in the image below.

I can tell there's a mirror modifier on but how does one make this model (without sculpting, ideally)
Edit: I realise that the Björk mask might be quite complex to describe in a post. I've added a second image which seems easier but still on similar lines. If that helps or if you have any other suggestions for explaining the direction, it would be greatly appreciated.
Edit: Created a cube, subdivided it thrice, added a mirror modifier. Quickly realised that I have no idea how to make wavy designs, gave it up.


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

You model it by adding cubes, extruding quads, cuting loops and making faces. Do you know the hotkey / tools for thoses actions in Blender?

What have you tried yourself so far?

@Joachim i only started but realised that i may not be going about it the right way. Or maybe this is an advanced design for a technique that needs to be practiced more. Also added an edit in the post above but I kind of gave it up.

@Leander yes, I'm certainly aware of this technique and the hotkeys but may need to practice it more. (I also added an edit above to show what I did but I quickly gave it up since I dont know how to make the wavy designs)

You did everything correctly, except giving up. Especially giving up quickly will be very bad for your progress. Try again and not give up. I blocked the base in 1-2 minutes. It is just extrusion and loop cuts and deleting unwanted geometry. Maybe the wireframe will give you some inspiration. To make this, you should complete 5 beginner organic modelling tutorials and 5 beginner hard surface modelling tutorials. (Complete! not watch/consume.) Then expect to invest at least 10h into constantly trying to find your shapes of this mask.

That's just my advice though. Maybe someone else will post a fancy answer about generating depth maps through AI and projecting them in Blender. ^^

@Leander This advice is incredibly helpful! Thank you. I'm really glad to know I was on the right track—I just needed to be more patient and see it through. Do you have any recommendations for YouTube channels? Lastly, it seems the link is broken

Sorry, I don't know much about tutorials. But if you successfully follow some humanoid modeling tutorials, you will be ready for all the next steps. A quick search revealed a lot of videos: Example, Example. And here was a screenshot of my start: https://i.imgur.com/8wkdSDv.png.

@Leander Thank you so very much! I dont know how you did it but hopefully I can figure this out after completing some modelling tutorials.
